# unable to find all the links using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get all the links on this webpage:-

"https://vajiramandravi.com/upsc-daily-current-affairs/prelims-pointers/d/2-January-2023/"

But I am not able to find all the links in python.

Can someone please help to let me know how to get all the links on this webpage.

Below is the code I am using:-

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://vajiramandravi.com/upsc-daily-current-affairs/prelims-pointers/d/2-January-2023/'
driver.get(url)


all_links = []
while True:
    links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    all_links.extend(links)

for link in all_links:
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
    if href:
        print(href)
```

I see this on inspecting on chrome:-

```
<h1 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h1 article-title pointer css-1c43ib7">King Penguin live on Antarctic and sub –Antarctic.</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://vajiramandravi.com/upsc-daily-current-affairs/prelims-pointers/d/2-January-2023/')
all_links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
for link in all_links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
driver.quit()
```